# Sending signed transactions to Ropsten

Tags: ethereum, web3js

It's easy to use web3js to call functions that don't require signing (e.g. functions that do not update the state of a contract). However, it's not clear how to call functions that require signing, other than manually unlocking my MetaMask wallet and calling functions inside [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) environment.

After deploying my dapp for the first time to Ropsten, I need to call `createItem(string name, uint price)` 100 times to populate the `items` array initially. Since I don't want to do it manually in Remix, I want to write a script that does it automatically.

It looks like I need to have `ethereumjs-tx` in addition to `web3js` to sign transactions programatically without having MetaMask. I also need to have my `account` and `privateKey`. With all this information and the official web3js doc, I come up with the following:

```
// Call an external function programatically

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io"))
const account = "ACCOUNT_ADDRESS"
const privateKey = new Buffer('PRIVATE_KEY', 'hex')
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, CONTRACT_ADDRESS, {
  from: account,
  gas: 3000000,
})

const functionAbi = contract.methods.myFunctionName(myArgument).encodeABI()

let estimatedGas
contract.methods.myFunctionNAme(myArgument).estimateGas({
  from: account,
}).then((gasAmount) => {
  estimatedGas = gasAmount.toString(16)
})

const txParams = {
  gasPrice: '0x' + estimatedGas,
  to: CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
  data: functionAbi,
  from: account,
}

const tx = new Tx(txParams)
tx.sign(privateKey)

const serializedTx = tx.serialize()

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')).
  on('receipt', console.log)
```

The code runs, but `txParams` is actually missing one key: `nonce`. When you run this, you get the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Returned error: nonce too low
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is this generally the right way to do what I am trying to do?
2. If 1 is true, how do I get the `nonce` parameter for a deployed contract?

*References:*

1. http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/
2. https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx
3. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21402/web3-eth-call-how-can-i-set-data-param
4. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6368/using-web3-to-sign-a-transaction-without-connecting-to-geth

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to Adam, now I learned how to get the `nonce`. So I added this following code:

```
let nonce
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account).then(_nonce => {
  nonce = _nonce.toString(16)
})

const txParams = {
  gasPrice: '0x' + gasPrice,
  to: CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
  data: functionAbi,
  from: account,
  nonce: '0x' + nonce,
}
```

But now I keep running into this exception:

> Unhandled rejection Error: Returned error: rlp: input string too long
>   for uint64, decoding into
>   (types.Transaction)(types.txdata).AccountNonce

Google search wasn't helpful except for letting me locate this file (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/rlp/decode.go) that has the exception handler. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: In your update you have async (Promise) code updating `nonce` after you've already used it in the TX object. That object can only see that updated nonce state if it's run inside the same `then` block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally looks correct. The only question I would have is how are you planning on loading the private key? You will either need to prompt for the private key, or import/read in the keystore and prompt for the password. You can use [keythereum](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum) to accomplish this (See the [key import](https://github.com/ethereumjs/keythereum#key-import) section for example code).

The `nonce` is just an incremental number used to order transactions for an account. To get the correct value, simply use `web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account)`

EDIT - Example run using Ganache with locked accounts (`--secure` option):

**SimpleContract.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract SimpleContract {
  uint public val = 4;

  function increment(uint amt) public {
    val += amt;
  }

  function get() public constant returns (uint) {
    return  val;
  }
}
```

**test.js**

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');

const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545");
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const account = '0x9a6d82ef3912d5ab60473124bccd2f2a640769d7'; // Ganache
const privateKey = Buffer.from('70f1384b24df3d2cdaca7974552ec28f055812ca5e4da7a0ccd0ac0f8a4a9b00', 'hex');
const contractAddress = '0x6dd7c1c13df7594c27e0d191fd8cc21efbfc98b4'; // Deployed manually
const abi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"val","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"get","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"amt","type":"uint256"}],"name":"increment","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}];

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress, {
  from: account,
  gasLimit: 3000000,
});

const contractFunction = contract.methods.increment(3);

const functionAbi = contractFunction.encodeABI();

let estimatedGas;
let nonce;

console.log("Getting gas estimate");

contractFunction.estimateGas({from: account}).then((gasAmount) => {
  estimatedGas = gasAmount.toString(16);

  console.log("Estimated gas: " + estimatedGas);

  web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account).then(_nonce => {
    nonce = _nonce.toString(16);

    console.log("Nonce: " + nonce);
    const txParams = {
      gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000',
      gasLimit: 3000000,
      to: contractAddress,
      data: functionAbi,
      from: account,
      nonce: '0x' + nonce
    };

    const tx = new Tx(txParams);
    tx.sign(privateKey);

    const serializedTx = tx.serialize();

    contract.methods.get().call().then(v => console.log("Value before increment: " + v));

    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')).on('receipt', receipt => {
      console.log(receipt);
      contract.methods.get().call().then(v => console.log("Value after increment: " + v));
    })
  });
});
```

Results:

```
$ npm run my_test

> hello_world_dapp@1.0.0 my_test C:\cygwin\home\adamk\eth\hello_world_dapp
> node ./test.js

Getting gas estimate
Estimated gas: 6919
Nonce: 5
Value before increment: 19
{ transactionHash: '0xb6fdfc36cc32cb01a2be8832a387da586a44a37c1241bbf2979745536f206ed4',
  transactionIndex: 0,
  blockHash: '0xb6ee8d4e45585010d9a12d48aa37a478eb6021aad78599f1719cb424ab364bb5',
  blockNumber: 10,
  gasUsed: 26905,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 26905,
  contractAddress: null,
  logs: [],
  status: 1 }
Value after increment: 22
```

Comment: Hey Adam, thanks a lot! I still couldn't send the transaction with the nonce value though. Do you mind taking a look at the updated question?

Comment: Hmmm....everything else looks correct. Seems like the error is telling you that your transaction count is too big, which seems weird. What is the final value of `txParams.nonce`?

Comment: `nonce` comes out to be something like `21` and I convert it to hex and prepend it with `0x`

Comment: Double check the rest of your logic, your promises, etc. I just ran a similar example using locked accounts in Ganache and it worked just fine. I'll update my answer with my sample code, configuration, and output. It could also be your configuration specific as it relates to using Infura, which I believe requires you to create a token and use a special configuration in Truffle. See Truffle's [tutorial](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider). I would recommend verifying your code works locally before integrating with Infura.

Comment: Adam, thank you! It works fine in a local environment (both with ganache-cli and truffle console) but with ropsten, it hangs and throws this: `Transaction was not mined within 50 blocks, please make sure your transaction was properly send. Be aware that it might still be mined!` Can you try changing your provider to `const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io");` and try the same code one more time?

Comment: Might be related to https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1102 if you can reproduce it on your end as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code-snippet for sending signed transaction on rinkeby.In a similar way,you can proceed for ropsten test network:

```
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx')
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 =new 
Web3('https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/9ce80a86c6c54d22aa821d0486a1a47d')


var account1 = '0xa00c70B72150D627cf53872eefD077079116B6a6'
var account2 = '0xD2a8aa318Fbc56995Db8C415BE6E40329DB1C56C'

const privateKey1 = Buffer.from(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_1,'hex')
const privateKey2 = Buffer.from(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_2,'hex')

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1,(err,txCount)=>{
const txObject = {
nonce:web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
to:account2,
value:web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.1','ether')),
gasLimit:web3.utils.toHex(21000),
gasPrice:web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10','gwei')),
}
console.log(txObject)
const tx = new Tx(txObject)
tx.sign(privateKey1)

const serializedTransaction = tx.serialize()
const raw = '0x'+serializedTransaction.toString('hex')

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw,(err,txHash)=>{
console.log(txHash)
})

})
```